# Why is it commonly stated in textbooks that no preferred inertial reference frames exist?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

According to formulations in most textbooks, the principle of relativity states that the laws of motion are the same in all inertial frames, that all inertial frames are equivalent, and **that no preferred (privileged) inertial frames exist**.  And therefore, **for two objects moving in uniform inertial motion relative to one another, it's impossible to determine which one is moving, and which one is at rest** .
So far, so good .

But when it later comes to the Doppler effect for sound, then, all of a sudden, it turns out that preferred inertial frames may nevertheless exist -  for instance, the inertial frame of  the air (or other medium) .
And not only that, but **it *is* possible to determine for the source and for the observer, which one of them is moving, and which one is at rest** (relatively to the frame of the medium) . **And this is not considered a violation of the principle of relativity.**

To avoid such inconsistency, wouldn't it be reasonable to add to standard formulations of the principle of relativity a note about medium being a preferred inertial frame, which may make it possible to determine, which one of two objects (moving inertially relative to one another) is moving, and which one is at rest (relatively to the frame of the medium) ?

Of course, this does not make a preferred frame an absolute frame .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doppler shift and Galilean relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257039/)

Comment: You are not thinking clearly. You are using the phrase 'preferred reference frame' to mean two different things, and then, surprise surprise, you find they conflict with each other. The point about the principle of relativity is that if you say the source (or observer) is moving relative to the medium, you can also consider the medium to be moving  and the source (or observer) to be stationary.

Comment: You actually _typed out_ the words "for sound"!

Answer (score 3):

Sound are propagating waves in a medium. So yes, it makes sense to talk about the relative velocity of the medium and an observer. You could define the medium as defining a frame, and then you could say whether an observer was moving or not with respect to that frame. In fact, we do this in our Universe: the cosmic frame is the rest frame of the cosmic microwave background radiation, where (averaging over large enough scales) matter tends not to move.

BUT.

*Light* **cannot** be described as a wave propagating in a medium.$^\star$ By an analogy with the case of sound waves, people in the late 1800s *thought* that light should propagate in some kind of medium, and this hypothetical medium was called the ether. Experiments like the Michelson-Morley experiment confidently ruled out the existence of the ether in our Universe. Special relativity has at its core a rejection of the idea that there is a medium in which light travels. When special relativity texts talk about the absence of a preferred rest frame, they are referring to this fundamental fact about space, time, and the propagation of massless particles like photons which is *always true* in the domain of validity of special relativity, and not the fact that a given collection of matter will define a *useful* reference frame for some specific situations.

---

$^\star$ I recently learned on this site of a formulation of special relativity called [Lorentz ether theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_ether_theory), where there is a preferred frame in which light travels through a medium that is at rest. But, this formulation requires a number of ad hoc assumptions related to length contraction and time dilation that conspire such that you can never actually observe the existence of this special frame in any experiment. Since at the end of the day the "special frame" can never be detected even in principle, I would categorize the existence of this formulation as an amusing footnote, but not a deep fact about the universe (hence, why I wrote a footnote); certainly, it is not the mainstream way to think about relativity.

Answer (score 2):

(a) "it is possible to determine for the source and for the observer, which one of them is moving, and which one is at rest (relatively to the frame of the medium)". That's because it's possible to tell which one is moving and which one is at rest *relative to the medium itself.* Your set-up involves 3 bodies: source, medium and observer. This would be the case in whatever frame of reference the experiment were conducted.

(b) The gist of Principle of Relativity is that if we perform the same experiment in two inertial frames of reference, moving at constant relative velocity with respect to each other, we will get the same results.

Suppose that in one frame we have a stationary source, a stationary medium and an observer moving away from the source. We can derive the equation
$$f_o=\left(1-\frac{v_o}w\right)f_s\ \ \ \text{in which $w$ is the speed of sound}$$
In another frame, moving at constant velocity with respect to the first, we have a stationary source, a stationary medium and an observer moving away from the source, we also find
$$f_o=\left(1-\frac{v_o}w\right)f_s$$
So, in accordance with the Relativity Principle, there is no preferred inertial frame of reference. But we have to be doing the same experiment in both frames, and that experiment involves a stationary medium. So if we are doing the experiment in a train moving at constant speed we need the windows closed so that there isn't a wind blowing through our laboratory.

In the case of light, before Einstein the usual view was that we couldn't actually do the same experiment in both frames because there was only one frame in which the medium for the propagation of light (the (a)ether) could be stationary. What appeared to be the same experiment should give simpler results in that frame. Einstein cut  through this by proposing that what *appeared* to be the same experiment *was* the same experiment; any supposed medium was at best irrelevant. [This seemingly innocent proposal required radical changes to our concepts of time and space.]

Comment: The info here is good and accurate, but I'm downvoting this because it doesn't answer or engage with the question. The user seems to be asking how does the apparent preference for the rest frame of medium of sound square with Galilean or special relativity.

Comment: @Maximal Ideal  I see no reference in the question to Galilean or Einstein/Lorentz relativity. The question is about privileged frames of reference and the role of a medium. That's what my answer deals with. Although I don't agree that the downvote is justified on the grounds you give, I thank you for giving me a reason.

Comment: This answer has helped me a lot. I was confused on why sound having a preferred reference frame did not conflict with Galilean relativity but light having a preferred reference frame did. Is it just because for the case of sound, Galilean relativity is not broken if the medium also receives a "boost" but they could not find the medium for light which posed a problem?

Comment: Yes, I think we're in agreement. It's worth noting, though, that the failure of attempts to find differences in light propagation due to relative motion of the laboratory through a hypothetical medium was not the major driving force behind Einstein's Special Theory.

Answer (score 1):

> But when it later comes to the Doppler effect for sound, then, all of a sudden, it turns out that preferred inertial frames may nevertheless exist -  for instance, the inertial frame of  the air (or other medium) .
> And not only that, but **it *is* possible to determine for the source and for the observer, which one of them is moving, and which one is at rest** (relatively to the frame of the medium).

That last part in parentheses is the key part. Relativity says all velocity can be stated only with respect to something else. Since in this case we are talking about velocity relative to the stationary frame of the medium (i.e. the frame where there is no net wind), it follows that relativity is not violated.

Notice that the stationary frame of the medium of sound doesn't have any fundamental significance. You could imagine a scenario with two mediums that are moving relative to each other (for example consider two different planets that are carrying their own atmospheres and going in different directions). In that case, notice that it is no longer obvious what frame is "privileged" or "preferred."